# Trouble testing plugin with object manager

Tags: magento2, plugin, object-manager

**Issue:** When attempting to test a plugin "after" method with `$objectManager->create('Shopgate\Base\Model\Config')->startup()`, the original `startup()` method is called but not my plugins `afterStartup()`

**Steps Taken:**

- [✔] Confirm module enabled & loaded
- [✔] Clear cache with `magento cache:clean config`
- [✔] Empty generated code with `rm -r generated/*`
- [✔] Register plugin as shown below:

In my `etc/di.xml`, I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Shopgate\Base\Model\Config">
        <plugin name="bugFixEnableGetSettings" type="MoninGlobal\ShopgateBugfix\Plugin\ShopgateConfig" sortOrder="9999" />
    </type>
</config>
```

In `MoninGlobal\ShopgateBugfix\Plugin\ShopgateConfig` I have:

```
    public function afterStartup($subject, $result){
        var_dump(get_class($subject));
        var_dump($result);

        return $result;
    }
```

The same occurs when using `get()` instead of `create()` on the object manager.

Any insight into what I am missing here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Despite Magento showing that the module had been loaded and enabled, my registration.php was incorrect:

**Bad**

```
use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'MoninGlobal_Template', # <--- BAD REFERENCE
    __DIR__
);
```

**Good**

```
use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'MoninGlobal_ShopgateBugfix',
    __DIR__
);
```